# Facebook Chat API Permission

Tags: android, facebook, chat

I have integrated facebook chat API in my android app to send messages to my friends.

1. If I dont have native facebook app in my android phone, I will allow facebook permissions from a web browser i.e., m.facebook.com on an internet browser. When this is done, I am able to successfully send messages to any/all of my friends.
2. If I give permissions from a native facebook app, I am having exceptions. It says Authorization failed.

I am suspecting this could be because chat api are deprecated in latest native facebook sdk.
Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer, I forcefully asked the user to login via Dialog Auth instead of facebook for Android app and it worked well. Only flaw that, when session expires, one has to enter his/her username/password repeatedly.